# Raspberry pi, libarmmem.so (cannot open shared object file) error

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm using my Pi as a file server, recently when I logged in I saw a error message stating that libarmmem.so (cannot open shared object file), and despite some suggestions to run apt-get update + upgrade it did not bring much joy as it freezes the progress and just hanging.

Does anyone have any suggestion what else I could try other than reflash the card, which i would like to avoid.

From the console after  "sudo apt-get update":

```
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Fri Feb 24 15:55:35 2017 from vpn.lshtm.ac.uk
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
/usr/bin/xauth: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
admin@ProxyPi:~$ sudo apt-get update
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
0% [Working]ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://archive.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
12% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main armhf Packages
Hit http://archive.raspbian.org jessie/main Sources
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://archive.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Sources
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages
Hit http://archive.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Sources
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi armhf Packages
Hit http://archive.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Sources
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

And here is after suggested libfix command :

```
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Fri Feb 24 15:39:44 2017 from vpn.lshtm.ac.uk
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
/usr/bin/xauth: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
admin@ProxyPi:~$ sudo ldconfig -v
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf' given more than once
/opt/vc/lib:
        libmmal_core.so -> libmmal_core.so
        libmmal_components.so -> libmmal_components.so
        libopenmaxil.so -> libopenmaxil.so
        libmmal.so -> libmmal.so
        libWFC.so -> libWFC.so
        libEGL.so -> libEGL.so
        libvcsm.so -> libvcsm.so
        libmmal_util.so -> libmmal_util.so
        libvchiq_arm.so -> libvchiq_arm.so
        libdebug_sym.so -> libdebug_sym.so
        libGLESv2.so -> libGLESv2.so
        libbcm_host.so -> libbcm_host.so
        libOpenVG.so -> libOpenVG.so
        libmmal_vc_client.so -> libmmal_vc_client.so
        libvcos.so -> libvcos.so
        libcontainers.so -> libcontainers.so
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:
        libm.so.6 -> libm-2.19.so
        librt.so.1 -> librt-2.19.so
        libpcre.so.3 -> libpcre.so.3.13.1
        libreadline.so.6 -> libreadline.so.6.3
        libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2 -> libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
        libdbus-1.so.3 -> libdbus-1.so.3.8.13
        libnss_mdns_minimal.so.2 -> libnss_mdns_minimal.so.2
        libmemusage.so -> libmemusage.so
        libdevmapper-event.so.1.02.1 -> libdevmapper-event.so.1.02.1
        libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.19.so
        libSegFault.so -> libSegFault.so
        libkmod.so.2 -> libkmod.so.2.2.8
        libiw.so.30 -> libiw.so.30
        libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.19.so
        libthread_db.so.1 -> libthread_db-1.0.so
        libgpg-error.so.0 -> libgpg-error.so.0.13.0
        libpam.so.0 -> libpam.so.0.83.1
        libntfs-3g.so.852 -> libntfs-3g.so.852.0.0
        libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.24
        libcryptsetup.so.4 -> libcryptsetup.so.4.6.0
        libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
        libprocps.so.3 -> libprocps.so.3.0.0
        libhistory.so.6 -> libhistory.so.6.3
        libisccfg-export.so.90 -> libisccfg-export.so.90.1.0
        libudev.so.1 -> libudev.so.1.5.0
        libnl-3.so.200 -> libnl-3.so.200.19.0
        libdevmapper.so.1.02.1 -> libdevmapper.so.1.02.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s.so.1
        libusb-1.0.so.0 -> libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
        libpam_misc.so.0 -> libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
        libfuse.so.2 -> libfuse.so.2.9.3
        libnss_mdns.so.2 -> libnss_mdns.so.2
        libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.9
        libattr.so.1 -> libattr.so.1.1.0
        libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.19.so
        libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.19.so
        libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.19.so
        libselinux.so.1 -> libselinux.so.1
        libgcrypt.so.20 -> libgcrypt.so.20.0.3
        libparted.so.2 -> libparted.so.2.0.1
        libirs-export.so.91 -> libirs-export.so.91.0.0
        libudev.so.0 -> libudev.so.0.13.0
        libpopt.so.0 -> libpopt.so.0.0.0
        libss.so.2 -> libss.so.2.0
        libsysfs.so.2 -> libsysfs.so.2.0.1
        libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.3.0
        libncursesw.so.5 -> libncursesw.so.5.9
        liblzma.so.5 -> liblzma.so.5.0.0
        libmount.so.1 -> libmount.so.1.1.0
        libacl.so.1 -> libacl.so.1.1.0
        libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.19.so
        libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.4200.1
        libpng12.so.0 -> libpng12.so.0.50.0
        libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.19.so
        libatasmart.so.4 -> libatasmart.so.4.0.5
        libbsd.so.0 -> libbsd.so.0.7.0
        libwrap.so.0 -> libwrap.so.0.7.6
        libpamc.so.0 -> libpamc.so.0.82.1
        libnss_mdns6_minimal.so.2 -> libnss_mdns6_minimal.so.2
        libsystemd.so.0 -> libsystemd.so.0.3.1
        libaio.so.1 -> libaio.so.1.0.1
        libslang.so.2 -> libslang.so.2.3.0
        libply.so.2 -> libply.so.2.1.0
        libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.19.so
        liblzo2.so.2 -> liblzo2.so.2.0.0
        liblvm2app.so.2.2 -> liblvm2app.so.2.2
        libply-boot-client.so.2 -> libply-boot-client.so.2.1.0
        libe2p.so.2 -> libe2p.so.2.3
        libtinfo.so.5 -> libtinfo.so.5.9
        libanl.so.1 -> libanl-2.19.so
        libblkid.so.1 -> libblkid.so.1.1.0
        libc.so.6 -> libc-2.19.so
        libusb-0.1.so.4 -> libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
        libnss_mdns6.so.2 -> libnss_mdns6.so.2
        libsmartcols.so.1 -> libsmartcols.so.1.1.0
        libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.19.so
        libbz2.so.1.0 -> libbz2.so.1.0.4
        libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.6.0
        libply-splash-core.so.2 -> libply-splash-core.so.2.1.0
        libnss_mdns4.so.2 -> libnss_mdns4.so.2
        libnl-genl-3.so.200 -> libnl-genl-3.so.200.19.0
        libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8
        libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.19.so
        libtirpc.so.1 -> libtirpc.so.1.0.10
        libply-splash-graphics.so.2 -> libply-splash-graphics.so.2.1.0
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.19.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

        ld-linux-armhf.so.3 -> ld-2.19.so
        libBrokenLocale.so.1 -> libBrokenLocale-2.19.so
        libdns-export.so.100 -> libdns-export.so.100.2.2
        libaudit.so.1 -> libaudit.so.1.0.0
        libsepol.so.1 -> libsepol.so.1
        libjson-c.so.2 -> libjson-c.so.2.0.0
        libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.19.so
        libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.19.so
        libnfsidmap.so.0 -> libnfsidmap.so.0.3.0
        libpcprofile.so -> libpcprofile.so
        libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.19.so
        libulockmgr.so.1 -> libulockmgr.so.1.0.1
        libkeyutils.so.1 -> libkeyutils.so.1.5
        libext2fs.so.2 -> libext2fs.so.2.4
        libisc-export.so.95 -> libisc-export.so.95.5.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:
/sbin/ldconfig.real: File /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtCLucene.so.4.8 is empty, not checked.
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtXmlPatterns.so.4.8 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtXmlPatterns.so.4 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: File /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtCLucene.so.4.8.6 is empty, not checked.
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtNetwork.so.4.8 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: File /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtCLucene.so.4 is empty, not checked.
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtXmlPatterns.so.4.8.6 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.
```

Comment: Did you ever stumble into a solution for this? I'm having the same issue now, not very long into my fresh Raspbian installation.

Comment: Hi not reallly, it quite a while now but i recall battling with this for few days and eventually gave it up and went for fresh install - as it was more time efficient that way. never had the same issue after that.

Comment: Thank you. Ended up just doing a fresh install too.

Answer (score 37):

I experienced the same error coming from a snapd 'snap'. I went into the preload file mentioned

`sudo nano /etc/ld.so.preload`

and commented the offending line out from

`/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so`

to

`#/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so`

Comment: This fixed my issue that I spent probably 40 minutes working on, so thank you!

Comment: Real MVP right here.

Answer (score 4):

### 1. Get you plataform

Check your platform in `/proc/cpuinfo` using command below

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name';
```

In my case (Raspberry Pi 4), return:

```
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
```

You can view the options for **ARM memory library**, using command below:

```
ls /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem*
```

In my case, return:

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-aarch64.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v6l.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v8l.so
```

Then, according with `/proc/cpuinfo`, I need to use `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so`, because exist a library for my platform:

| CPU info results | List Results |
| --- | --- |
| ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (**v7l**) | /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-**v7l**.so |

### 2. Setup Dynamic Linker

Change preload of dynamic linker using command below:

```
sudo nano /etc/ld.so.preload
```

Using nano editor, replace

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so
```

or in my case

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATAFORM}.so
```

by

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so
```

or according your platform.

Comment: While this seems to be the correct answer, the only thing that worked for me was to comment out the line in `/etc/ld.so.preload`.

Comment: Commenting Dynamic Linker do not resolve the problem, but disable configuration entry, disabling, in this case, The ARM Memory Library. It can generate a unexpected environment, may cause problems with ELF applications that need this resource.

Comment: @D.H.B.Marcos what you are saying makes sense, however, on a pi that prints the very same info as yours the fix did not work i.e. hello-world still prints "ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored".

Comment: @eglasius, I have identified that the fault is in "${PLATAFORM}". The Bash ou sh should interpret and replace this variable at run "/etc/ld.so.preload". Try set environmental variable in "/etc/environment" or before trouble line. Check the path and existence of library in "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/". I hope this helps.

Comment: To me it was not the PLATFORM variable that is the problem as changing still gives the same problem
ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded

Answer (score 0):

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ hello-world

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v8l.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
Hello World!

only commenting the line with # worked but I don't know the its implication.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the installed .so files and none worked. So the simple solution was

```
sudo rm /etc/ld.so.preload
```

It is not an important file, it only affects some  memcpy and memset performance, which in my case doesn't matter.
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135169/what-exactly-is-libarmmem-platform-so-and-how-to-update-it